# Which official LEGO sets are micro-scale versions of existing sets?

Tags: sets, micro-scale, modular-buildings

The **[10230 Mini Modulars](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=10230-1)** set is  based on the existing modular series:

[image]

As well as the **[4695 Mini Harry Potter Knight Bus](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=4695-1)**. Have there been other micro-scale sets released by LEGO based on existing sets?

Comment: There are a large number of Star Wars themed micro-scale sets (a number of which they are re-releasing in the collectible planets with a minifig) that were based on larger sets.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid: I know about those too, but they're sold as a set , like in a calender.

Comment: Which ones do you mean are sold as a set - the Buildings or the SW ones? All of the sets listed in [Star Wars Minis](http://www.peeron.com/inv/theme/LEGO/SYSTEM/Star_Wars/Mini) were sold separately, and had larger sets they were based on.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid: Oh. I thought you meant [this](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=7958-1).

Comment: The problem with this question, is to decide which sets are actually mini/micro versions of other sets, and which sets are made after the same _original_, but just on another scale. With the _Mini Modulars_ it's obvious they're based on the bigger sets. But _Star Wars_ sets have been made in a range of scales, some of which happen to be micro. Do these count? And crocodiles are crocodiles, so does [20015](http://brickset.com/sets/20015-1/Crocodile) count as a smaller version of [5868](http://brickset.com/sets/5868-1/Ferocious-Creatures)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(M) = Microscale

#### Harry Potter

- [4841](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=4841-1) Hogwarts Express,
  (M) [40028](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=40028-1) Mini Hogwarts Express
- [4755](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=4755-1) Knight Bus,
  (M) [4695](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=4695-1) Mini Harry Potter Knight Bus

#### Modular

- [10182](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=10182-1) Cafe Corner,
  [10190](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=10190-1) Market Street,
  [10185](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=10185-1) Green Grocer,
  [10197](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=10197-1) Fire Brigade,
  [10211](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=10211-1) Grand Emporium,
  (M) [10230](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=10230-1) Mini Modulars

#### Pirates of the Caribbean

- [4184](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=4184-1) The Black Pearl,
  (M) [30130](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=30130-1) Mini Black Pearl

#### Star Wars

- [Various](http://brickset.com/sets?query=tie%20fighter) TIE Fighter, (M) [3219](http://brickset.com/sets/3219-1/Mini-TIE-Fighter) Mini TIE Fighter
- [Various](http://brickset.com/sets?query=millennium%20falcon) Millennium Falcon (M) [4488](http://brickset.com/sets/4488-1/Millennium-Falcon) Millennium Falcon and (M) [75030](http://brickset.com/sets/75030-1/Millennium-Falcon) Millennium Falcon
- [Various](http://brickset.com/sets?query=at-at) AT-AT Walker, (M) [4489](http://brickset.com/sets/4489-1/AT-AT) AT-AT
- [7675](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=7675-1) AT-TE Walker,
  (M) [20009](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=20009-1) AT-TE Walker
- [8098](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=8098-1) Clone Turbo Tank,
  (M) [20006](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=20006-1) Clone Turbo Tank
- [7163](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=7163-1) Republic Gunship,
  (M) [20010](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=20010-1) Republic Gunship
- [7674](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=7674-1) V-19 Torrent,
  (M) [8031](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=8031-1) V-19 Torrent
- Lots of Mini's in the Advent Calendars, [7958](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=7958-1) 2011, [9509](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=9509-1) 2012
- [10019](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=10019-1) Rebel Blockade Runner,
  (M) [10030-1](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=10030-1) Imperial Star Destroyer contains micro version

#### Technic

- [8053](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=8053-1) Mobile Crane,
  (M) [8067](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=8067-1) Mini Mobile Crane
- [8275](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=8275-1) Motorized Bulldozer,
  (M) [8259](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=8259-1) Mini Bulldozer
- [8295](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=8295-1) Telescopic Handler,
  (M) [8045](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=8045-1) Mini Telehandler
- [8069](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=8069-1) Backhoe Loader, (M) [42004](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=42004-1) Mini Backhoe Loader

#### Creator

- [31003](http://brickset.com/sets/31003-1/Red-Rotors) Red Rotors, (M) [30184](http://brickset.com/sets/30184-1/Little-Helicopter) Little Helicopter
- [31004](http://brickset.com/sets/31004-1/Fierce-Flyer) Fierce Flyer, (M) [30185](http://brickset.com/sets/30185-1/Little-Eagle) Little Eagle
- [31020](http://brickset.com/sets/31020-1/Twinblade-Adventures) Twinblade Adventures, (M) [30189](http://brickset.com/sets/30189-1/Transport-Plane) Transport Plane
- [6743](http://brickset.com/sets/6743-1/Street-Speeder) Street Speeder, (M) [6910](http://brickset.com/sets/6910-1/Mini-Sports-Car) Mini Sports Car

#### Misc.

- [10226](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=10226-1) Sopwith Camel, (M) [40049](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=40049-1) Mini Sopwith Camel
- [10220](http://brickset.com/sets/10220-1/Volkswagen-T1-Camper-Van) Volkswagen T1 Camper Van, (M) [40079](http://brickset.com/sets/40079-1/Mini-VW-T1-Camper-Van) Mini VW T1 Camper Van

#### Possible

- [10194](http://brickset.com/sets/10194-1/Emerald-Night) Emerald Night, (M) [31015](http://brickset.com/sets/31015-1/Emerald-Express) Emerald Express
- [8110](http://brickset.com/sets/8110-1/Mercedes-Benz-Unimog-U-400) Mercedes Benz Unimog U 400, (M) [9390](http://brickset.com/sets/9390-1/Mini-Tow-Truck) Mini Tow Truck

Comment: This post is Community Wiki, Please add any other sets you may know .

Comment: There was also the micro Rebel Blockade Runner, included in 10030 Imperial Star Destroyer

Comment: I added some, but there lots more in the Creator theme.

Answer (score 2):

There's also a [mini hogwarts express](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=40028-1):

[image: 40028-1 - mini hogwarts express]

And you probably can count the Liberty Statue in the [Skyline factory set](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=5526-1):

[image: 5526-1 - Skyline]

Most other minis are indeed from [Star Wars](http://www.brickset.com/search/?subtheme=Mini%20Building%20Set&query=mini), but I'm not sure which ones have bigger versions.

Comment: Every single Star Wars mini on that page had a corresponding larger version, some had more than one scale.